# ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist in Mac - SQLPLUS

Tags: oracle, macos, sqlplus

I have installed sqlplus instantclient in Mac OS X EI Captain.

I am able to connect to database by typing the below command in terminal

`sqlplus uname/pwd@//localhost:1521/myDB`

I need to connect to database without full connection string, Just i need to type `sqlplus` then i enter username and password, this is throwing below error.

```
ERROR:
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

I have below environment variables set and tnsnames.ora is created.

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/instantclient
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME
export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8
export TNS_ADMIN=~/etc
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME  
export ORACLE_SID=myDB
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error.

Below is the tnsnames.ora under ~/etc location.

```
myDB =
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost) (PORT = 1521))
        (
            CONNECT_DATA =
            (SERVER = DEDICATED)
            (SERVICE_NAME = myDB)
        )
)
```

Comment: Yes, it was a typo.i use 'sqlplus' command it prompts for username and password then it gives this error. "ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist"

Comment: Try one thing. In tnsnames.ora, check that there is no typo and actually have `(HOST = localhost)`. If yes, try changing `localhost` with the actual name of you machine. ex `TOM-PC` or with `127.0.0.1` or with the current LAN IP address of you PC that you get with `ifconfig`

Comment: i was getting the same error and what fixed it for me was to use the fully qualified domain name for my remote machine at work (i.e. mydb.mydomain.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`TWO_TASK` environment variable](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NETAG/concepts.htm#NETAG363) to define the default connect string, e.g.

```
export TWO_TASK=${ORACLE_SID}
```

Also test the configuration with `tnsping myDB`.